# Jquery namesession error in IE 8

Tags: jquery

I got this error in some IE 8 browsers.

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Fri, 11 Mar 2011 20:48:23 UTC

Message: 'JSON' is undefined
Line: 6
Char: 3
Code: 0

Message: '$.namesession' is null or not an object
Line: 53
Char: 2
Code: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using `JSON.stringify` somewhere in your code which is not part of jquery. It is natively built in modern browsers but this might not be your case. So make sure you include [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) in your page as well.